# inApp Purchase problem?

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

once i perform in- app purchase i make unlock my feature for my application then some how user can uninstall application. then some time he download app.. and run it how to recognize user already purchase application....

is their any payment state we have to check for that user on applicatinDidFinishLaunching... method than what can i check i have no idea about it please help me on this...

i m thank full for helping please possible than reply me fast.........

Answer (score 0):

I found this [tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/) by Mugunth Kumar to be the best one for starters ,go through it,very descriptive content over there with nice explanation.

Comment: hey some new prob occur ahead i implement in app... please reply me as fast as possible